# Flutter || Use Firestore instead of Mock Data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how can I remove the Mockdata and use my Google Firestore Data?

```
Future<List<AppProfile>> _findSuggestions(String query) async {
    if (query.length != 0) {
      return mockResults.where((profile) {
        return profile.name.contains(query) || profile.email.contains(query);
      }).toList(growable: false);
    } else {
      return const <AppProfile>[];
    }
  }
}

// -------------------------------------------------

const mockResults = <AppProfile>[
  AppProfile('Stock Man', 'stock@man.com', 'https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX4057996.jpg'),
  AppProfile('Paul', 'paul@google.com', 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/person-stock-image-png.png'),
];

class AppProfile {
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String imageUrl;

  const AppProfile(this.name, this.email, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) || other is AppProfile && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Profile{$name}';
  }
}

// -------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a screenshot of my structure in Firebase:

[image]

Help is really aprecciated, because I dont know how to continue...

Beste Regards